how can i fix my poping problem in my shopping cart
i m working on a shopping cart with 5 options and i struggle with the option 3 to remove (pop) an item.
right now it only shows me one item even when i added more items to the list. i need that it shows me all the items and then i can input the number of one item and then its getting poped(not removed). and it i but in an invalid number then it should loop back and ask me again to but in acorrect number.
how you can tell by the code i tried a few different things. i put in the whoöe code because i made the mistake outside from the option 3
#shopping cart with the 5 options

items = []
prices = []
ite_pri = items + prices

index = 0
name = None
cost = 0

print('Welcome to the Shopping Cart Program!') 

while name != 'quit':
    
    print()
    print('Please select one of the following: ')
    print('1. Add item \n2. View cart \n3. Remove item \n4. Compute Total \n5. Quit')
    
    option = input ('Please enter an action: ')
    #1. option is to add a item stored in list items and prices, aks how for price and new: how many
    if option == '1':
      name = input('What item would you like to add? ')
      cost = input(f"What is the price of '{name}'? ")
      quantity = input(f"How many '{name}'? ")
      print(f"'{name}' has been added to the cart. ")
      items.append(name)
      prices.append(float(cost) * int(quantity))

# 2. option is to show cart
    elif option == '2':
       print()
       print('The content of the shopping cart are:')
      
       for i in  range(len(items)):
       
            name = items[i]
            cost = prices[i]
   
            print(f'{i+1}.{name} - ${cost}')
# 3. option is to remove (pop) an item
# it only shows one item and befor that it poped the wrong item (when i press 2 it poped the 3. item)
    elif option == '3':
       print()
       print('The content of the shopping cart are:')
      
       for i in  range(len(items)):
       
            name = items[i]
            cost = prices[i]
   
            print(f'{i+1}.{name} - ${cost}')
            
       pop_index = int(input('Which item would you like to remove? ')) 
       if index == pop_index: 
      
               items.pop(int(pop_index))
               break

       print('Item removed.')
                  
       # how can i make it that if user tips in an invalit number that this print comes and he has to but in a new number       
       print('sorry, that is not a valid item number.')
        

# 4. option is to show total
    elif option == '4':
      running_total = 0
      
      for total in prices:
        running_total += float(total)
       
      print(f'The total price of the items in the shopping cart is: {running_total:.2f}')
       


# 5. option is to stop the progress
    elif option == '5':
     print('Thank you. Goodbye.')
     #name != 'quit'
     break
     


@SIGHUP There is an answer from 1 hour ago which already says that.

@mkrieger1 so what? Anyone looking at this question will see comments before answers

index is always 0, you should increment it when you add one item. when you're printing the content of the cart, you're starting valid pop_index values at 1. by your own logic the if condition if index == pop_index should never be fulfilled. what you want is checking if it's in the item range. this should work
    pop_index = int(input('Which item would you like to remove? '))
    if (pop_index-1) in range(len(items)):

        items.pop(pop_index-1)
        print('Item removed.')

    else:
        # how can i make it that if user tips in an invalit number that this print comes and he has to but in a new number
        print('sorry, that is not a valid item number.')


Creating a range is unnecessary. All you need to know is if the pop index is less than the length. pop_index-1 < len(items). Really, all you need is a try/except block and don't worry about checking anything. This gets rid of subtraction, creating a range, gathering the item length, and the branch.

@OysterShucker if you check, i think you'd have to check also if it's positive. try/except does the trick wonderfully indeed, but i was trying to answer with minimal changes in op's logic

Create a class for shopping item and store them in a shopping cart array of ShoppingItem object instead of using 2 arrays. This refactored code should solve your issue
class ShoppingItem:
    def __init__(self, name, price, quantity):
        self.name = name
        self.price = float(price)
        self.quantity = int(quantity)

    def total_price(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} - ${self.price:.2f} x {self.quantity} = ${self.total_price():.2f}"


class ShoppingCart:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []

    def add_item(self, name, price, quantity):
        self.items.append(ShoppingItem(name, price, quantity))
        print(f"'{name}' has been added to the cart.")

    def view_cart(self):
        if not self.items:
            print("Your cart is empty.")
        else:
            print("\nThe contents of the shopping cart are:")
            for i, item in enumerate(self.items, 1):
                print(f"{i}. {item}")

    def remove_item(self, index):
        if 0 <= index < len(self.items):
            removed_item = self.items.pop(index)
            print(f"Removed '{removed_item.name}' from the cart.")
        else:
            print("Sorry, that is not a valid item number.")

    def compute_total(self):
        total = sum(item.total_price() for item in self.items)
        print(f"\nThe total price of the items in the shopping cart is: ${total:.2f}")

    def is_empty(self):
        return len(self.items) == 0


def main():
    cart = ShoppingCart()

    print('Welcome to the Shopping Cart Program!')

    while True:
        print()
        print('Please select one of the following:')
        print('1. Add item \n2. View cart \n3. Remove item \n4. Compute Total \n5. Quit')

        option = input('Please enter an action: ')

        # 1. Add item
        if option == '1':
            name = input('What item would you like to add? ')
            price = input(f"What is the price of '{name}'? ")
            quantity = input(f"How many '{name}'? ")
            cart.add_item(name, price, quantity)

        # 2. View cart
        elif option == '2':
            cart.view_cart()

        # 3. Remove item
        elif option == '3':
            if cart.is_empty():
                print("Your cart is empty. Nothing to remove.")
            else:
                cart.view_cart()
                try:
                    pop_index = int(input('Which item would you like to remove? ')) - 1
                    cart.remove_item(pop_index)
                except ValueError:
                    print("Invalid input. Please enter a valid item number.")

        # 4. Compute total
        elif option == '4':
            cart.compute_total()

        # 5. Quit
        elif option == '5':
            print('Thank you. Goodbye.')
            break

        else:
            print("Invalid option. Please select a valid action.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

